# Mono for Android, WebView input field filechooser doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, file-upload, webview, xamarin.android

I have the web page that uses to upload files. User selects file with `<input type="file" />` and presses submit button, all works fine. Now I need to create android application (on C# with mono for android) which contains of simple webview and has to work like web version.

But I stumbled on the problem - when I click on `Choose file` button then file dialog doesn't open.

I googled this problem few days but I didn't find any solution. Looks like there is [workaround on Java platform](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.com/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html), but it doesn't work on C#.

Have someone any ideas how to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea how to make it work. Part of it is bog-standard "how to bind a virtual method," and part of it is pure unmitigated evil.

Firstly, we need an "intermediary." Since `WebChromeClient` doesn't declare the `openFileChooser()` method, we need to declare a version that does so, named `OpenFileWebChromeClient`. It declares a `virtual` `OpenFileChooser` method, and provides a binding for it so that it can be overridden:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace Scratch.FileUpload
{
    [Register ("android/webkit/WebChromeClient", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    class OpenFileWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient {

        static IntPtr id_openFileChooser;
        [Register ("openFileChooser", "(Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V", "GetOpenFileChooserHandler")]
        public virtual void OpenFileChooser (IValueCallback uploadMsg)
        {
            if (id_openFileChooser == IntPtr.Zero)
                id_openFileChooser = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (ThresholdClass, "openFileChooser", "(Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V");

            if (GetType () == ThresholdType)
                JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod  (Handle, id_openFileChooser, new JValue (JNIEnv.ToJniHandle (uploadMsg)));
            else
                JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod  (Handle, ThresholdClass, id_openFileChooser, new JValue (JNIEnv.ToJniHandle (uploadMsg)));
        }

#pragma warning disable 0169
        static Delegate cb_openFileChooser;
        static Delegate GetOpenFileChooserHandler ()
        {
            if (cb_openFileChooser == null)
                cb_openFileChooser = JNINativeWrapper.CreateDelegate ((Action<IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr>) n_OpenFileChooser);
            return cb_openFileChooser;
        }

        static void n_OpenFileChooser (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_uploadMsg)
        {
            OpenFileWebChromeClient __this = Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<OpenFileWebChromeClient> (native__this, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            var uploadMsg = Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<IValueCallback> (native_uploadMsg, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer);
            __this.OpenFileChooser (uploadMsg);
        }
#pragma warning restore 0169
    }
}
```

Next, since C# lacks anonymous inner classes, we need an explicit class, named `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient` here:

```
namespace Scratch.FileUpload {
    class MyOpenFileWebChromeClient : OpenFileWebChromeClient {

        Action<IValueCallback> cb;

        public MyOpenFileWebChromeClient(Action<IValueCallback> cb)
        {
            this.cb = cb;
        }

        public override void OpenFileChooser (IValueCallback uploadMsg)
        {
            cb (uploadMsg);
        }
    }
```

The Activity port is ~identical to the blog post you referred to, except that it uses `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient` instead of the anonymous inner class. I've also updated some logic to display the URI that `OnActivityResult()` receives:

```
namespace Scratch.FileUpload {

    [Activity (Label = "Scratch.FileUpload", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        private WebView wv;
        private IValueCallback mUploadMessage;
        const int FilechooserResultcode = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            wv = new WebView (this);
            wv.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            wv.SetWebChromeClient(new MyOpenFileWebChromeClient(uploadMsg => {
                        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                        var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionGetContent);
                        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
                        intent.SetType("image/*");
                        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "File Chooser"),
                            FilechooserResultcode);
            }));

            SetHtml(null);

            SetContentView(wv);
        }

        void SetHtml(string filename)
        {
            string html = @"<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>Input Box:</p>
<input type=""file"" />
<p>URI: " + filename + @"
</body>
</html>";
            wv.LoadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == FilechooserResultcode) {
                if (mUploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                var result = data == null || resultCode != Result.Ok
                    ? null
                    : data.Data;
                SetHtml(result.ToString());
                mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, it is now time for the act of pure unmitigated evil. The problem with the above declaration for `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient` is that it won't work, for the same reason that M0S' blog couldn't use `@Override` in the anonymous inner class declaration: the `android.jar` that you build your app against doesn't declare the `openFileChooser()` method.

The build process will generate [Android Callable Wrappers](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture/android_callable_wrappers), which must contain valid Java code. The problem is that the generated code uses `@Override` for overridden methods and interface methods, resulting in the Android Callable Wrapper for `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient`:

```java
package scratch.fileupload;


public class MyOpenFileWebChromeClient
extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient
{
    static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "n_openFileChooser:(Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V:GetOpenFileChooserHandler\n" +
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("Scratch.FileUpload.MyOpenFileWebChromeClient, Scratch.FileUpload, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", MyOpenFileWebChromeClient.class, __md_methods);
    }

    @Override
    public void openFileChooser (android.webkit.ValueCallback p0)
    {
        n_openFileChooser (p0);
    }

    private native void n_openFileChooser (android.webkit.ValueCallback p0);

    java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

Obviously the `@Override` on `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient.openFileChooser()` will generate a compiler error, so how do we make this work? *By providing our own `@Override` annotation!*

```
package scratch.fileupload;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Override {
}
```

Place the above into a file named `Override.java`, add it to the project, and set its Build action to `AndroidJavaSource`.

The resulting project works because we provide a custom `@Override` annotation in the same package as the `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient` type. (This consequently requires that you know what the generated package name will be, and that you provide a separate `@Override` annotation for every package that you do this for.) Types in the same package take precedence over imported names, even names coming from `java.lang`, so our custom `@Override` annotation not only compiles, it's used by the `MyOpenFileWebChromeClient` android callable wrapper in preference to the `java.lang.Override` annotation.

I did say it was pure unmitigated evil, didn't I?

Comment: Mother of god! That is some workaround to get this to work. Luckily it has been fixed in Mono for Android 4.2! http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_For_Android_4.2#Bug_Fixes

Comment: Is this fixed. File upload popup not working in webview on my side

Answer (score 0):

step1 =
    File upload will work , we need to give Read / Write permission in android manifest.
    in Main Activity.cs

```
step2=
private Action<int, Result, Intent> resultCallbackvalue;

public void StartActivity(Intent intent, int requestCode, Action<int, Result, Intent> resultCallback)
{
this.resultCallbackvalue = resultCallback;
StartActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (this.resultCallbackvalue != null)
{
this.resultCallbackvalue(requestCode, resultCode, data);
this.resultCallbackvalue = null;
}
}
step3= add ExtendedChromeClient,cs Inheriting from : WebChromeClient

private static int filechooser = 1;
private IValueCallback message;
private MainActivity activity = null;

  public ExtendedChromeClient(MainActivity context)
    {
        this.activity = context;
    }

  public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
    {
        this.message = filePathCallback;
        Intent chooserIntent = fileChooserParams.CreateIntent();
        chooserIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
        this.activity.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(chooserIntent, "File Chooser"), filechooser, this.OnActivityResult);
        return true;
    }

  private void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (requestCode == filechooser)
            {
                if (null == this.message)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.message.OnReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.ParseResult((int)resultCode, data));
                this.message = null;
            }
        }
    }
```